# Echonest API Migration questions

Tags: spotify, echonest

I use the Echonest API currently to convert between ID spaces (MusicBrainz -> SeatGeek). With the upcoming migration to the Spotify API, I'm wondering if there will be any endpoint for Project Rosetta.  This is a pretty crucial feature of my application.

Comment: Bump.  Any info on this?? If this api feature is going to be dropped, that should be made clear asap.

Comment: I'm as clueless and as curious you. I'm working on something similar. Nothing new so far?

Comment: @PedroOtero Nothing yet.  I actually just dropped them an email so I'll answer this question if I hear back!