# Spotify API - Get track foreign ID

Tags: spotify, deezer, echonest

Since Spotify announced to close *Echo Nest API* and migrate several methods in [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2016/03/29/api-improvements-update/), I decided to implement theses new functions now.

Like *Echo Nest API*, is it possible to get a track with a foreign ID like Deezer ? Or to get the foreign ID of a Spotify track ? At May 31 maybe ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no info about it. No one can tell. I already know of another developer hoping for the same. He asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657505/echonest-api-migration-questions) and [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/232). You can see that he posted on Spotify web api Github site and got no answer.